# Is it possible to use multiline text in object attribute in CleverMaps?

Tags: attributes, metadata, clevermaps

I need to display more lines in one attribute in CleverMaps. If it is possible, is it also somehow possible to format it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on whether you want to use it in the **primary** or **secondary** attribute.

You can save a string to the data that displays multiple lines of HTML (something like `Sally<br>Taylor`), but the UI of application has a statically set **primary** attribute height, so this breaks the layout at this point.

[See how it breaks the layout on this screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlRPQ.png)

However it works fine on the **secondary** attribute type.

[See how it works on secondary attribute](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZCDx.png)

Formatting (using Markdown) is currently supported only in the project description.